# Keep Popup Open when Opening a new Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code to introduce my Chrome Extension.

```
// detect if this is the first time running
var first_run = false;
if (!localStorage['ran_before']) {
    first_run = true;
    localStorage['ran_before'] = '1';
}

// if not, start the intro() script
if (first_run) intro();

// intro script
function intro() {
    window.open("intro/index.html", '_blank');
}
```

But sadly, when I click the extension, it doesn't open the `popup.html` but just opens the intro page.. it needs to keep the `popup.html` open and I'm sure there is a way to do this. *I want to open them both at the same time.*

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you wan to open `popup.html`, you probably shouldn't be calling `window.open("intro/index.html")`.

Comment: @DanielBeck Actually, I want to open them both at the same time.

Comment: Where is the code that's supposed to open `popup.html`?

Comment: @DanielBeck It doesn't require code, the user clicks the icon at the top right to open the extension.

Comment: So is the code we're looking at from popup.html?

Comment: @AndyArndt This script is executed from the `popup.html`, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Marc Guiselin's answer is excellent, it may be useful to know how to open a tab without closing a popup.

You could open the tab in the background, that way it won't close your popup.

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  url: chrome.runtime.getURL("intro/index.html"),
  active: false
});
```

In general, you should avoid using `window.open` in extensions and use `chrome.tabs` and `chrome.windows` API instead.

Comment: That worked, but it opens the tab in the background, is there a way possible to open in the foreground?

Answer (score 3):

the method you are using is valid and should work, but you should probably
just use the onInstalled event for consistency:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(info){
    if(info.reason == "install"){
        console.log("Installed!");
    }else if(info.reason == "update"){
        console.log("Updated!");
    }
});
```

It doesn't require new permissions, and will keep your install code clearly separated from the rest of your code.